# How to include external JS file in Angular and how to call it in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-forms

Let's say I have a file named index.js which has a function expression

```
  $scope.submit = function() {
  if ($scope.username && $scope.password) {
  var user = $scope.username;
  var pass = $scope.password;
  if (pass == "admin" && user == "manoj@admin.com") {
    alert("Login Successful");
    jQuery(location).attr('href', 'http://google.com')
  } else if (user != "manoj@admin.com") {
    alert("Invalid username");
  } else if (pass != "admin" && user == "manoj@admin.com") {
    alert("Invalid password");
  }
 }
}.
```

I want to call that function in my Angular project. How should I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are trying to use AngularJS based function expression in Angular which is not correct.

There is nothing like `$scope` in Angular.

If are okay with modifying your function, do something like this.

In `index.js`

```
export function submit(username, password) {
  if (username && password) {
    var user = username;
    var pass = password;
    if (pass == "admin" && user == "manoj@admin.com") {
      alert("Login Successful");
      jQuery(location).attr('href', 'http://google.com')
    } else if (user != "manoj@admin.com") {
      alert("Invalid username");
    } else if (pass != "admin" && user == "manoj@admin.com") {
      alert("Invalid password");
    }
  }
}
```

And in file where you want to use it.

```
import submit from index.js

submit('usr', 'pwd');
```

Comment: @Asish Do we need to include the path of js file in angularcli ?

Comment: No need. When angular-cli encounters `import submit from index.js`  statement it automatically includes it in build.

Comment: Hello, @Ashish I tried everything as you said. While clicking on submit button it's only showing the invalid user all the time.Even its displaying invalid on page reload Can you help me out.

Comment: Are you getting alert msg as "Login Successfull" when you are calling submit("manoj@admin.com",  "admin")?

Comment: no. I'm getting only login unsuccessful msg all the time, irrespective of the alert message

Answer (score 0):

just export the function from the index.js file and then import it in the files you want.
Either attach that function to the window object like `window.myFunction = myFunction` and add the index.js as a script tag in your html.